# PDO: database credentials

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am trying to make my own Database class. Although I have declared all credentials the errors tell me that there is no database specified.

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog
>   name: 1046 No database selected in
>   /var/www/html/jwagter/work/database/Database.php:69 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/jwagter/work/database/Database.php(69):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   /var/www/html/jwagter/work/database/tutorial.php(22):
>   Database->execute() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/jwagter/work/database/Database.php on line 69

index.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "secret");
define("DB_NAME", "test");

require 'Database.php';


$database = new Database();

$database->query('INSERT INTO mytable (FName, LName, Age, Gender) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :age, :gender)');

$database->bind(':fname', 'Joris');
$database->bind(':lname', 'Wagter');
$database->bind(':age', '27');
$database->bind(':gender', 'male');

$database->execute();

echo $database->lastInsertId();
```

Database.php

```
<?php
class Database
{

private $host = DB_HOST;
private $user = DB_USER;
private $pass = DB_PASS;
private $dbname = DB_NAME;

private $dbh;
private $error;

private $stmt;

public function __construct()
{

    echo "in class Database";

    $dsn = 'mysql:host' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );

    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    } catch (PDOExeption $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }

}

public function query($query)
{

    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
{

    if (is_null($type)) {

      switch (true) {
        case is_int($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
          break;
        case is_bool($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
          break;
        case is_null($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
          break;
        default:
          $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
      }

    }

    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);

}

public function execute()
{
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function resultset()
{
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function single()
{
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function rowCount()
{
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}

public function lastInsertId()
{
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}


public function beginTransaction()
{
    return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
}

public function endTransaction()
{
    return $this->dbh->commit();
}

public function cancelTransaction()
{
    return $this->dbh->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: There is at least one typo in your DSN string. Besides, your Database class [suffer from many common mistakes](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: thank you, I will look into the link you sent me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get *No database selected* and database is specified in the DSN string then the error must be there. You have this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
```

You should print it for diagnose. It'll look like this:

```
mysql:hostlocalhost;dbname=test
```

Now the typo is clear.

Comment: Ouch, I forgot the = how stupid. Thanks for the suggesting to print it.

Answer (score 0):

Id take into account the link in the comment given by Your Common Sense,

You can try putting the database name in your query to get things moving.

```
$database->query('INSERT INTO test.mytable (FName, LName, Age, Gender) 
VALUES (:fname, :lname, :age, :gender)');
```

Or a USE DATABASE before you do your query.

```
$database->query("USE DATABASE test");
$database->execute();
```

Id abandon writing the database wrapper however, with the reasons highlighted in the link above. PDO is pretty good.